# Cannot connect to proxy error on requests.get() or requests.post() in python

Tags: python, proxy, request, python-requests, http-proxy

I have two URLs to fetch data from. Using my code, the first URL is working, whereas the second URL is giving `ProxyError`.

I am using `requests` library in Python 3 and tried searching the problem in Google and here, but with no success.

My code snippet is:

```
    import requests

    proxies = {
      'http': 'http://user:pass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx',
      'https': 'http://user:pass@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx',
    }

    url1 = 'https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/act'
    url2 = 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/act'

    r1 = requests.get(url1, proxies=proxies)
    r2 = requests.get(url2, proxies=proxies)
```

`url1` works fine, but `url2` gives following error:

```
    ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dictionary.cambridge.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dictionary/english/act (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',)))
```

Same happens on using `request.post()`

1. Please explain me why this is happening, and is there any difference between the handshaking of both the URLs?
2. `urllib.request.urlopen` is working fine, so I am explicity looking for answers using `requests`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to illicit a  valid response for `url2` when using headers keyword argument with `User-Agent` string set to `Chrome`.

```
r2 = requests.get(url2, proxies=proxies, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome'})
```

To answer your first question, possible reason for this happening is related to server-side settings. It might be configured not to accept requests originating from unknown agents or requests with a missing `User-Agent` header.

Comment: Worked like charm. That means that the website is checking for the agent which is making a request, and will response only to a browser. Any link where I can study this behaviour?

Comment: Yes. That seems to be the case. Thanks for accepting my answer. :)

Comment: apache server specific example: https://serverfault.com/questions/251988/blocking-apache-access-via-user-agent-string

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql
import time, datetime
import os

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter


def get_random_proxy():
    proxypool_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5555/random'
    """
    get random proxy from proxypool
    :return: proxy
    """
    return requests.get(proxypool_url).text.strip()


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Chrome',
    'Referer': 'https://www.nmpa.gov.cn/datasearch/home-index.html?79QlcAyHig6m=1636513393895',
    'Host': 'nmpa.gov.cn',
    'Origin': 'https://nmpa.gov.cn',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Connection': 'close'
}
url = 'https://www.nmpa.gov.cn/datasearch/search-result.html'


def start_requests(coo):
    # r = json.loads(r.text)
    headers['Set-Cookie'] = coo
    s = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, stream=True, timeout=(5, 5), verify=False)
    s.encoding = 'utf8'
    print(s.status_code)
    print(s)


while True:
    proxy = {'http': 'http://' + get_random_proxy(), 'https': 'https://' + get_random_proxy()}
    print(proxy)
    try:
        sess = requests.Session()
        sess.keep_alive = False  # 关闭多余连接
        res = sess.get(url='https://nmpa.gov.cn', headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome'}, proxies=proxy, timeout=10,
                       verify=False)
        res.close()
        print(res.status_code)
        res.encoding = 'utf8'
        cookie = res.headers['Set-Cookie']
        print(cookie)
        if res.status_code == 200:
            print(res.status_code)
            time.sleep(10)
            start_requests(cookie)
            break
    except Exception as error:
        time.sleep(10)
        print("没有连接成功", error)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.